# Returning empty value from JTextBox from standalone class

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way or is it possible to create actionListener as a standalone class?
i manage to create the button listener withing the loginView class and it works perfectly fine but what i am trying is to achieve login function from another class(LoginLogic).

The problem i faced , when i tried to println , its returning nothing.

**loginView.java**

```
loginLogic lg1 = new loginbtn
final JTextField user;
JButton login = new JButton("test");

user = new JTextField;
..
..
..
panel.add(lg1.loginBtn(user.getText()), cs)

// ----  This will work but i am trying to load the function from loginLogic----
//  login.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
//  @Override
//  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
//  String userText = user.getText();
//  System.out.println(username);
//  });

}
```

**loginLogic.java**

```
..
public class loginLogic{
public Component loginbtn(String username){
JButton login = new JButton("submit");
login.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
System.out.println(username);
});
return login;
}
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) **Besides providing the `String` text to the `loginbtn` method, you might also pass a reference to the text field.** 4) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous inner classes like below have a meaning only inside another class, because what point is to have actionlistener to another class if the only class who uses it is the JFrame class. The only purpose i see is *maybe* clean code.

If you want to implement actionListener to a separate class you can:

```
public class ClickListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Clicked!");
    }
}
```

and then to your JFrame class:

```
button.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
```